# Optimizing query which checking if user_id exists in many tables

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a problem with optimization of my query (bigquery is showing me that it will process 26 GB of data and I don't want to consume all this data...). I want to check if user_id exists in 4 different tables and return name of the platform if it will find it in one of them. Is there any way to optimize this logic maybe even without using all these cases?

```sql
CASE
   WHEN a.user_id in (SELECT safe_cast(USER_ID as int64) FROM `platform1_table`
   where front_date >= "2016-01-01") THEN "platform1"
   ELSE NULL
END AS platform1,
CASE
   WHEN a.user_id in (SELECT safe_cast(USER_ID as int64) FROM `platform2_table`
   where front_date >= "2016-01-01") THEN "platform2"
   ELSE NULL
END AS platform2,
CASE
   WHEN a.user_id in (SELECT safe_cast(USER_ID as int64) FROM `platform3_table`
   WHERE date(snapshot_time)>= "2016-01-01") THEN "platform3"
   ELSE NULL
END AS platform3,
CASE
   WHEN a.user_id in (SELECT safe_cast(USER_ID as int64) FROM `platform4_table`) THEN "platform4"
   ELSE NULL
END AS platform4
```

Comment: BigQuery is reporting on the total volume of the columns used in the query.  Your query looks reasonable, so it is not clear how it can be improved from a cost standpoint.

Answer (score 0):

You can try out Joining Condition

```
SELECT 
CASE
   WHEN b.USER_ID IS NOT NULL THEN "platform1"
   ELSE NULL
END AS platform1,
CASE
   WHEN c.USER_ID IS NOT NULL THEN "platform2"
   ELSE NULL
END AS platform2,
CASE
   WHEN d.USER_ID IS NOT NULL THEN "platform4"
   ELSE NULL
END AS platform3,
CASE
   WHEN e.USER_ID IS NOT NULL THEN "platform4"
   ELSE NULL
END AS platform4
FROM MAIN_TABLE a 
LEFT JOIN `platform1_table` b on a.user_id = safe_cast(b.USER_ID as int64)
LEFT JOIN `platform2_table`c ON a.user_id = safe_cast(c.USER_ID as int64)
LEFT JOIN `platform3_table`d ON a.user_id = safe_cast(d.USER_ID as int64)
LEFT JOIN `platform4_table`e ON a.user_id = safe_cast(e.USER_ID as int64)
WHERE a.front_date >= "2016-01-01"
and b.front_date >= "2016-01-01"
and date(c.snapshot_time)>= "2016-01-01"
```

Though this solution you can minimize processed data by implementing PARTITION & CLUSTERING over Joining & filtering Fields.

This solution will be faster because we are Joining data `IN` utilize cashes.